# Get values from a different class

Tags: objective-c, return-value

I want to replace the title and message with the return values from a different class and also put it into an if statement that will see if the return value matches a value i state. can you help me out a little bit, this is my code below, I'm using theos by the way

the 3 methods i want to get the values for are

- -(id)title
- -(id)message
- -(id)_appName

from the SBBulletinBannerItem class
any help is appreciated

```
%hook SBBulletinBannerController

- (void)_handleBannerTapGesture:(id)reply

{
    reply = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Reply", nil];
    [reply show];
    [reply release];
}

%end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to use delegates and protocols. You may have seen this using standard Cocoa and Cocoa Touch classes. This is how you respond to events in a UITableView.

You can find examples of implementing this yourself [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html).

Comment: thank you, ill check it out and post back here if i still can't get it to work

Comment: i can't seem to figure this out, i have another class the gets the values, but idk how to link the values to show up in this class, idk the actual arguments